# separate string with html into two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to separate a string with html and non-html in it into two strings.

My javascript string is:

```
<span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity
```

I want this to be separated into two variables

```
var quantity = "1x";
var name = "Front-line zero tolerance productivity";
```

Comment: What kind of code are your trying to parse? Can there be nested tags?

Comment: I'm parsing the dom. The example is the only use case, nothing is nested.

Comment: It will always be a single nested span, followed by a space?

Comment: yeah single nested span, followed by a space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split when a `<span>` or `</span>` tag is found.

```
string = "<span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity"

tokens = string.split(/<\/?span>/);  // returns ["", "1x", " Front-line zero tolerance productivity"]
var quantity = tokens[1]  // "1x"
var name = tokens[2];     // "Front-line zero tolerance productivity"
```

Comment: +1 for first correct answer :) As the OP mentioned clearly that it as a string. DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Agfyk/5/ <<

Comment: What if the span isn't well formed or has a class? Would this fail?

Comment: @Marko: Yes. It will. Like every other mathod which relies too much on the string format.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way would be to use [jQuerys `contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) given that you will always have this type of markup.

**HTML**

```
<div id="split-me">
    <span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $contents = $("#split-me").contents();
var quantity = $contents.eq(1).text();
var name = $contents.eq(2).text();
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xnrNB/2/)

Comment: I like this answer! The indexing is off though 0 - 1 not 1 - 2

Comment: Thanks @ThomasReggi check out the demo, the index at 0 is an empty text node which is actually the space between the div an the span.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `<span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity` is wrapped inside a div like below,

```
<div id="test">
    <span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var $clonedTest = $('#test').clone();
var $span = $clonedTest.find('span');
var quality = $span.text();
$span.remove();
var name = $.trim($clonedTest.text());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Agfyk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since the format of the string won't change, you can split on the first space to get the two parts. Then remove tags from the first returned element, and preserve the structure of the second half:

```
var str = "<span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity";
var ndx = str.indexOf(" ");
var rst = []; // Array of results

rst.push( str.substr( 0,ndx ).replace(/<\/?.+?>/g,"") );
rst.push( str.substr( ndx+1 ) );
```

Which results in the following array:

```
["1x", "Front-line zero tolerance productivity"]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dBTKZ/

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very elegant, but you can use the javascript `.replace()` function for your second var, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#outp').html('first: ' + $('#inp span').html() + '<br/>' +
                    'second: ' + $('#inp').html().replace($('#inp span').html(),''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more dynamic and modular function to get all subtext blocks you want

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    texts: function() {
        var texts = [];
        var blocks = this.contents();
        $.each(blocks, function(i, block) {
            if(block.nodeName === '#text') {
                var data = $.trim(block.data);
                data && texts.push(data);
            } else {
                texts = jQuery.merge(texts, $(block).texts());
            }
        });
        return texts;
    }
});

$(function() {
    console.debug($('<span><span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity</span>').texts());            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <span>1x</span> Front-line zero tolerance productivity
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var matches = $('.container').html().match(/<span>(.*)<\/span> ?(.*)/);

var spanText = matches[1];   // 1x
var textNode = matches[2];   // Front-line zero tolerance productivity
</script>
```